# How does the manifest file link an activity tag with the activity file

Tags: android

I just started reading about android development and I am using Eclipse.
My question is how does the AndridManifest file know which xml file to call by using the information from the activity tag. For example , I just added a new activity and called it activity_two as a result eclipse generated two main files for me `ActivityTwo.java` and  `activity_activity_two.xml`. It also added the activity tag to the manifest file which is

```
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityTwo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_two" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Now my question is how does eclipse know that this tag is associated with `activity_activity_two.xml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't know layout file of any activity. 

Later, inside `OnCreate` method, you need to "give" Activity her layout file by writing simple line: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_two);`

Comment: One of the java fles haas `  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); .. }` Does this mean the name of activity is being passed to it ?

Comment: No super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) means that activity will call parent method with data, that has been stored before it destroys. That savedInstanceState is just a simple Map with some data inside.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing things.

`ActivityTwo.java`

Is your activity, where you will add your app code. In your manifest you have a `<manifest>` tag similar to the following, with a package declaration.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pedal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

so as you can see, package on my example is `com.example.pedal`.

And then later you on you have one or more Activity declaration inside your `<Application>` tag.

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
       <activity
        android:name=".ActivityTwo"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

so to find your activity file, it will join the package string, with your activity name:

`com.example.pedal.MainActivity`

In this example, there are two activities. The intent 
`<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`
defines which activity will be executed when the app is launched.

If you have different packages in your `/src` structure you can reference them using the full package name, with the class in the manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.PackageTwo.ActivityTwo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

`activity_activity_two.xml`

Is a layout file. There you will define the views which will be displayed in your activity. How it will look like, which buttons, textviews, whatever you decide, and as @Procurares replied above, that is defined using:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_two);`

[The developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) provides a very good guide on how Activities work.

Also answering your comment. I'm not really sure if the name of the activity is passed on the bundle(But I doubt). The information contained there is about the state of the activity in case it needs to be recreated. There is a very helpful post on the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810418/whats-oncreatebundle-savedinstancestate).