# Are fragments saved by default with savedInstanceState?

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

I read on [What's onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810418/whats-oncreatebundle-savedinstancestate)
that onsaveinstancestate gives you a bundle of the previous state of the application(if the orientation of the screen changed.

I looked on the Android docs(http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) and saw that you have to manually put the values you want saved as key value pairs. Their code for doing so was

```
    static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";
...

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);
```

My question is for fragments, are they automatically reattached when the orientation changes and the activity recreated? Would you have to put code to save it into a bundle?
Heres facebook code for this situation that I am trying to understand

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
    mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment)
    .commit();
} else {
    // Or set the fragment from restored state info
    mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep a fragment when an Activity gets destroyed, so it automatically reataches, you should call

```
Fragment.setRetainInstance(true)
```

in the Fragment's constructor.
Nothing is saved by default in `onSaveInstanceState()`

Comment: So they are not by default retained? That's what I thought too. What do you mean by the constructor? Do you mean the oncreate lifecycle method?

Comment: No, I mean that Fragment's constructor. If you have setRetainInstance(true) in it and the Activity gets destroyed the Fragment won't be destroyed.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1#dialogs makes no mention of this at all in the fragment. Do you know why?

Comment: I don't but you can refer here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)