# Advices about user's parameters

Tags: android-studio

I'm going to build an application used by many user, where the user can set some settings.
These settings can be some preferences and some "numbers"; and i'm not so strong in Android development. So what can you tell me about that, I mean where could I save these parameters (a file? saved on device?) because the application is accessible without a login, so preferences can't be saved on server.
Excuse me if this is a duplicated topic; because I really don't know what I want.
Thank you for attention !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from reading this article which is about [Managing Lifecycle of an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState).

In general you can use either the Bundle object to save your data and restore them everytime or probably use a less recommended way which is a database (SQLlite).

I'd recommend reading, comprehending and using the Bundle option.

And some extra reading with almost same questions:
[What's onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810418/whats-oncreatebundle-savedinstancestate)
[Saving Android Activity state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state)

Comment: And another reading material I just "stumbled" upon: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.htm